# Configure Windows firewall to prevent an application from listening on a specific port

Tags: windows, security, firewall, windows-firewall

The issue: there are many applications struggling to listen on port 80 (Skype, Teamviewer et al.), and to many of them that even is not essential (in the sense that you can have a `httpd` running and blocking the http port, and the *other* application won't even squeak about being unable to open the port). What makes things worse, some of the apps provide no way to configure the app **not to** use specific ports (that's what you get for using proprietary software) - you can either add it to Windows Firewall exceptions (and succumb to undesired port opening behavior) or not (and risk losing most - if not all - of the functionality).

Technically, it is not impossible for the firewall to deny an application opening an incoming port even if the application is in the exception list. And if this functionality is built into the Windows Firewall somewhere, there should be a way to activate it.

So, what I want to know is:

1. whether there exists such an option,
   and if it does
2. how to activate it.

---

EDIT: I wouldd like to stress that I am talking about the Windows Firewall version that is bundled with Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

After giving it a second thought, I realized that most likely this won't work, because as far as I know Windows firewall just blocks inbound packets. It never prevents an application opening a port for listening, just blocks the incoming traffic, if the port is not in the exceptions list.

Am I right or am I wrong? Any opinions on this?